# Is "Word" from Delphi an equivalent variable to "Char" on Java?

Tags: java, delphi, pascal, delphi-xe5, modbus

In Delphi, a Word is a 16 bits unsigned variable (0..65535)

> http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Word

The char variable in Java is a 16 bit Unicode variable (0..65535)

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

**I have the following code on Delphi**

```
procedure TForm1.ReadHoldRegisters(var lst: TList<byte>; deviceaddr: byte;
  RegisterAddress, RegisterLength: word);
begin

  lst.Add(deviceaddr);
  lst.Add(3);
  lst.Add(RegisterAddress div 256);
  lst.Add(RegisterAddress mod 256);
  Add_CRC16(lst);
end;

procedure TForm1.Add_CRC16(var Data: TList<byte>);
var
  CRC16Lo, CRC16Hi, CL, CH, SaveHi, SaveLo: byte;
  Flag: Integer;
  b: byte;
begin
  CRC16Lo := $FF;
  CRC16Hi := $FF;
  CL := $1;
  CH := $A0;

  for b in Data do
  begin
    CRC16Lo := CRC16Lo Xor b;
    For Flag := 0 To 7 Do
    Begin
      SaveHi := CRC16Hi;
      SaveLo := CRC16Lo;
      CRC16Hi := CRC16Hi Div 2;
      CRC16Lo := CRC16Lo Div 2;

      If ((SaveLo And $1) = $1) Then
      Begin
        CRC16Hi := CRC16Hi Xor CH;
        CRC16Lo := CRC16Lo Xor CL;
      End;



    End;
  end;
  Data.Add(CRC16Lo);
  Data.Add(CRC16Hi);
end;
```

**And it's equivalent on Java**

```
    public void ReadHoldRegisters(List<Byte> lst, byte deviceaddr, char RegisterAddress, char RegisterLength)
        {

            lst.add(deviceaddr);
            lst.add((byte) 3);
            lst.add((byte) (RegisterAddress/256));
            lst.add((byte) (RegisterAddress%256));

            Add_CRC16(lst);

        }

    private void Add_CRC16(List<Byte> Data)
    {
        char  SaveLo, SaveHi;
        int flag;


        char CRC16Lo =  0xFF;
        char CRC16Hi =  0xFF;
        char CL      =  0x1;
        char CH      =  0xA0;


        // início do for in
        for (Byte b : Data)
        {
            CRC16Lo = (char) ((CRC16Lo) ^ b);
            for(flag=0;flag<7;flag++)
            {
                SaveHi = CRC16Hi;
                SaveLo = CRC16Lo;
                CRC16Hi = (char) (CRC16Hi/2);
                CRC16Lo = (char) (CRC16Lo/2);
/*
                if((SaveHi & 0x1) == 0x1 )
                {
                    CRC16Lo = ((char) (CRC16Lo|0x80));
                }
*/
                if((SaveLo & 0x1) == 0x1 )
                {
                    CRC16Hi = ((char) (CRC16Hi^CH));
                    CRC16Lo = ((char) (CRC16Lo^CL));

                }
            }
        }
        // fim do for in

        CRC16Hi = (char) (CRC16Hi & 0xffff);
        CRC16Lo = (char) (CRC16Lo & 0xffff);

        Data.add((byte) CRC16Lo);
        Data.add((byte) CRC16Hi);

    }
```

When I print the values by doing

```
for (Byte b : lst)
S = S + String.format("%1X ", b);
```

I get `01 03 00 20 F0` on Delphi and `1 3 0 D8 D9` on Java.

Assuming that char and word are equivalent variables, what's going wrong with RegisterAddress and RegisterLength my code?

Comment: Delphi `Word` is an unsigned 16 bit type. I think Java `char` is the same. Is it possible that the difference is endian. Java is big endian, Delphi is little endian.

Comment: My other suggestion is that you do some debugging. Why be helpless? Get each program to log intermediate values. Discover where the programs diverge. Then you will understand the problem. And be able to solve it yourself.

Comment: If the difference is endian, would it be a change for the entire code or just it's final values?

Comment: For delphibasics' readers (and probably authors, as well) unsigned and Unicode are all the same stuff.

Comment: I don't know. I've not looked at the code. If you learnt how to debug you'd be in the happy position of being able to solve such problems yourself. It seems to me that somewhere along the way, we are all failing to teach beginners how to debug.

Comment: I'm debugging, Sir! Thank you by the way. I came out with a code where both languages work (edited answer). If I add to the List<Byte> a value before (RegisterAddress/256) it will work as expected. However, if I add a value to the list after (RegisterAddress/256) the values diverge.

Comment: I bet most SO questions asking "what is wrong with my code" end up with finding that an error is elsewhere.

Comment: I believe the line CRC16Lo = (char) ((CRC16Lo) ^ b); in the Java version is the problem. In Java byte is a signed type and when it gets promoted to a larger type it gets sign extended. So in the line above if "b" is negative (i.e. the high bit is 1) then when it is converted into a char the result will have have 0xFF as the high byte of the char. So for example, suppose b contains 0x80 then when you xor with b you will actually xor with 0xFF80 instead of 0xFF (if this is not clear see the sign-extension section of this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, a Delphi `Word` is an unsigned 16 bit type. The Java `char` likewise is an unsigned 16 bit type.

However, you mention `Word` in the question, but it doesn't appear in the code. Well, you use `Word` in `ReadHoldRegisters` but nowhere in `Add_CRC16` is the `Word` type used. So, you aren't using `Word`. You are using `Byte`. So, the two variants of `Add_CRC16` differ significantly because of that.

I've not looked at the rest of the code, but the mismatch between 8 bit `Byte` in Delphi and 16 bit `char` in Java is the most glaring issue. Start by fixing that problem, and see what comes next.

As a final aside, I recommend that you avoid the Delphi Basics website, especially for reference material. You are much better served by the official documentation. The relevant documentation for this question is [Delphi Data Types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Data_Types).

Comment: Thought it doesn't solve my code (that's something I'll have to deal with) it answers the question. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Surely a WideChar (classic Delphi) or just Char (Delphi 2009 onwards) would be more appropriate?

Comment: Would you please explain it more specifically? 

The Delphi code works how it should be. Java there might be missing something.

Comment: @penarthur66 Neither `Char` nor `WideChar` make much sense in the Delphi code because this is not a text operation. The Java code uses `char`, presumably, because it's the only unsigned type in the language. Delphi `Word` is a sound choice.